# What is wrong with my scroll down effect?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, scroll

I want to use a scroll down effect on my site. There I have several anchor links. The user should scroll smoothly to the link target when he uses the anchor link.

My HTML code looks like this (link with anchor):

```
<li class="indent1">
     <a href="#eigenschaften-dartscheibe" 
        onclick="test('eigenschaften-dartscheibe'); return false;">
             Welche Eigenschaften einer Dartscheibe sind entscheidend
     </a>
</li>
```

the content section where the link is targeted:

```
<h2 id="eigenschaften-dartscheibe" class="curtain">
   Welche Eigenschaften einer Dartscheibe sind entscheidend?
</h2>
```

and my Javascript:

```js
function scrollTo(to, duration) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop == to) return;
    var diff = to - document.body.scrollTop;
    var scrollStep = Math.PI / (duration / 10);
    var count = 0, currPos;
    start = element.scrollTop;
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if (document.body.scrollTop != to) {
            count = count + 1;
            currPos = start + diff * (0.5 - 0.5 * Math.cos(count * scrollStep));
            document.body.scrollTop = currPos;
        }
        else { clearInterval(scrollInterval); }
    },10);
}

function test(elID)
{
    var dest = document.getElementById(elID);
    scrollTo(dest.offsetTop, 500);
}
```

the scoll effect doesnt work... Where is my mistake? Can somebody help me?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `element` when you have not defined it. Use the Developer Tools -> Console for that (F12 or Right click -> inspect on Chrome).

Pass the element from `test` to `scrollTo`:

```
function test(elID)
{
    var dest = document.getElementById(elID);
    // Here (dest)
    scrollTo(dest, dest.offsetTop, 500);
}
```

Then use it to check when the scroll is finished:

```
if ((document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight - element.offsetHeight) < to) {
```

1. Calculate the scroll
2. Add window height
3. Subtract the elements height to make sure you reach the bottom

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdmfpjm2/

Comment: How so? Scrolls for me?

Comment: with firefox it doesnt scroll... you know why?

thanks

Comment: I am not sure to be honest.